# print arraylist element?

Tags: java

how do i print the element "e" in arraylist "list" out?

```
 ArrayList<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();
 Dog e = new Dog();
 list.add(e);
 System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do you want to print the entire list or you want to iterate through each element of the list? Either way to print anything meaningful your `Dog` class need to override the `toString()` method (as mentioned in other answers) from the `Object` class to return a valid result.

```
public class Print {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        List<Dog> list = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        Dog e = new Dog("Tommy");
        list.add(e);
        list.add(new Dog("tiger"));
        System.out.println(list);
        for(Dog d:list) {
            System.out.println(d);
            // prints [Tommy, tiger]
        }
    }

    private static class Dog {
        private final String name;
        public Dog(final String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
[Tommy, tiger]  
Tommy  
tiger
```

Answer (score 6):

First make sure that `Dog` class implements the method `public String toString()` then use

```
System.out.println(list.get(index))
```

where index is the position inside the list. Of course since you provide your implementation you can decide how dog prints itself.

Comment: I agree it would be reasonable to accept downvotes only together with a word of explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an updated solution for Java8, using lambdas and streams:

```
System.out.println(list.stream()
                       .map(Object::toString)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Or, without joining the list into one large string:

```
list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code requires that the `Dog` class has overridden the `toString()` method so that it knows how to print itself out. Otherwise, your code looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should override `toString()` method in your `Dog` class. which will be called when you use this object in sysout.

Answer (score 0):

Printing a specific element is

```
list.get(INDEX)
```

I think the best way to print the whole list in one go and this will also avoid putting a loop

Arrays.toString(list.toArray())

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print an arraylist with integer numbers, as an example you can use below code.

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0; i<=10; i++){
            arraylist .add(i);
        }
       for (Integer n : arraylist ){
            System.out.println(n);
       }
   }
}
```

The output is above code:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```