# Java toString ArrayList without Brackets

Tags: java, arraylist, formatting, tostring

I have been working on a toString method printing out the contents of an ArrayList. I was just wondering if someone could explain to me on how to break each individual Person, Age and DOB on a new line (\n) instead of having them print in one long array with brackets.

Here is the output for my code as well as the expected output.

```
expected Name: \n"Peter", Age: 16, DOB: Feb 15, 2000\n"Colin", Age: 15, DOB: March 12, 2001  
actual   Name: \n["Peter", Age: 16, DOB: Feb 15, 2000, "Colin", Age: 15, DOB: March 12, 2001]
```

Comment: I think this question has been answered already. Try looking here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047003/print-arraylist-element

Comment: What, you just want us to code this for you?

Comment: @ScaryWombat clearly if I have some actual output and some expected output I must have written the code, I was not asking someone to code this for me, merely asking how to split it up.

Comment: @GunnerStone thank you I shall have a look through and hopefully it explains how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (Java8) would be:

```
System.out.println(things.stream()
                         .map(Object::toString)
                         .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

But I'm guessing this is homework, so using Java8, lambdas, streams, map, and collector would all be off the table.